# Alternating VC branches to build deployment artifacts for different environments

Tags: jenkins, branch, subversion

We use `Jenkins` for CI. The app is written in `Java`, built with `Maven` (invoked manually in local dev environments and by Jenkins), deployed on various `Tomcat` servers. Nothing unusual about the application stack. Version control is `SVN` for the time being (we're looking at `Git` and I hope that comes soon).

We have a multi-phase Jenkins job called something like **build.all** which does `svn update` using the Maven plugin and then runs `mvn clean install` from the root dir where the code is checked out by svn. Then, another set of jobs deploys the artifacts made by **build.all** using [deploy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) by sending them over to the target servers using a Tomcat manager web service. The deploy jobs specify the latest successful build of **build.all** as the source of artifacts to deploy.

That works great when we are in a single branch mode. The hard setting of **build.all** as the source of artifacts to deploy is what is giving me headaches while trying to support transition periods during which some environments receive deployments from branch X and some from branch Y.

Without belaboring you with the minutiae of random low level tactics I'm speculating might make this possible -- can you recommend a high level strategy to support parallel artifact builds from different versioning branches? One goal is to not have to change the job source of artifacts to deploy because there is a rather large number of jobs that do deployments and changing them all by hand would be prohibitively labor intensive. For example, is there a way to maintain a key lookup mapping environments with source branches (or references thereof) so if a deployment job starts with *STAGE* or *UAT*, Jenkins looks up which build job (specific to a branch) is mapped to that environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a release process to manage deployments in your environments.
A plugin that can help you is the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/), where you 'freeze' the package and can promote them between environments (DEV -> UAT -> PROD). This ensures that the artifact (package) is exactly the same as the Production environment.